# How to restart Portainer on Ubuntu?

Tags: docker, portainer

I am on Ubuntu 22 have just installed Docker and Portainer, when I try to access it via IP:9000, I get a timeout message:

[image: timeout message]

"New Portainer installation
Your Portainer instance timed out for security purposes. To re-enable your Portainer instance, you will need to restart Portainer.

For further information, view our documentation."

At portainer.io forum people recomend the a command:

sudo docker start portainer

No result.

Also repeating the commnad:
sudo docker run -d -p 9000:9000 --name portainer --restart always -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v portainer_data:/data portainer/portainer

Only got a message on my SSH saying I would install another portainer, which I don't need.

On youtube tutorials, they open the IP immediately after installation, whithout the timeout bug.

Any clue?

Answer (score 37):

I ran:

```
sudo docker restart portainer
```

and it worked.

Comment: It should work without `sudo` but probably here it depends on the installation.

Answer (score 2):

1. First stop portainer

   docker stop portainer
2. Start portainer, again

   docker start portainer

For a reason I do not know, when I just restarted portainer, the prompt (see screenshot above) still persisted.

Answer (score 0):

docker stop CONTAINER ID
docker start CONTAINER ID

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).